Getting 401 from React App when using JWT Token - Axios
For some reason the Axios is returning 401, let me send all config that I am using. When using Swagger and Postman is working fine.

I have one Authentication in my Web Api responsible to generate the token and send it to the client, the client is saving it at sessionStorage.
When I calling the API passing the Bearer Token, I am getting the 401 error.

This is the Axios call:
getPatients: async (token: string): Promise<PatientDTO[]> => {
try {
  const response: AxiosResponse<PatientDTO[]> = await axios.get(
    `${API_BASE_URL}/patient`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  const patients = response.data.map((patient) => ({
    ...patient,
  }));

  return patients;
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error fetching patients:", error);
  throw error;
}
},

This is the ApiConfig, as you can see I am AllowAnyHeaders,
   services.AddCors(opt =>
   {
   opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
   {
       policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
   });
   });

  .AddAuthentication(item =>
  {
      item.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      item.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  })
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuer = false,
          ValidateAudience = false,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]))
      };
  });

Error:


The "Error 401 Unauthorized" indicates that your access token doesn't have the necessary permissions for the /patient API endpoint. This isn't an issue with axios.get(), but rather a permissions problem with your access token.

@BenchVue The Swagger and Postman is working perfect.

Try copy from 401 Error's the token to Postman. It can be verify the token is not an issue.
